# TipTap editor Freezing Browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tiptap

When i use tiptap editor for react and edit more than 3000 words, is going freeze and unresponsive page. Why this happen?
[image: Unresponsive Page]

PS(1): I think the problem is `useState`, i use it so much and render component based on useState like

```js
{ canPost && <Component/>}
```

PS(2): I try to remove component who use useState, but it's still crash. This is my editor extensions code:

```js
//// Node TipTap Extensions
import Document from "@tiptap/extension-document";
import Paragraph from "@tiptap/extension-paragraph";
import Text from "@tiptap/extension-text";

// mark tipap extension
import Bold from "@tiptap/extension-bold";
import Code from "@tiptap/extension-code";
import Highlight from "@tiptap/extension-highlight";
import Italic from "@tiptap/extension-italic";
import Link from "@tiptap/extension-link";
import Strike from "@tiptap/extension-strike";
import Underline from "@tiptap/extension-underline";

// other tiptap extensions
import Dropcursor from "@tiptap/extension-dropcursor";
import Gapcursor from "@tiptap/extension-gapcursor";
import History from "@tiptap/extension-history";
import Placeholder from "@tiptap/extension-placeholder";
import Related from "@/lib/tiptap/related";
import { TipTapImage } from "@/lib/tiptap/image";

// Block TipTap Extensions
import Ads from "@/lib/tiptap/ads";
import Blockquote from "@tiptap/extension-blockquote";
import CodeBlock from "@tiptap/extension-code-block";
import BulletList from "@tiptap/extension-bullet-list";
import ListItem from "@tiptap/extension-list-item";
import HardBreak from "@tiptap/extension-hard-break";
import Heading from "@tiptap/extension-heading";
import HorizontalRule from "@tiptap/extension-horizontal-rule";
import OrderedList from "@tiptap/extension-ordered-list";
import Table from "@tiptap/extension-table";
import TableCell from "@tiptap/extension-table-cell";
import TableHeader from "@tiptap/extension-table-header";
import TableRow from "@tiptap/extension-table-row";
import Youtube from "@tiptap/extension-youtube";
import Video from "@/lib/tiptap/video";
export const editorExtensions = [
  Ads,
  Bold,
  Blockquote,
  BulletList,
  Code,
  CodeBlock,
  Document,
  Dropcursor,
  Gapcursor,
  HardBreak,
  Heading.configure({
    levels: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  }),
  HorizontalRule,
  Highlight,
  History,
  Italic,
  Link.configure({
    openOnClick: false,
    HTMLAttributes: {
      rel: null,
    },
  }),
  ListItem,
  OrderedList,
  Paragraph,
  Placeholder.configure({
    placeholder:
      "Mulai menulis artikel dengan membaca bismillah dan akhiri dengan kata alhamdulillah, insya allah berkah...",
  }),
  Related,
  Strike,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TableHeader,
  Table.configure({
    resizable: true,
  }),
  Text,
  TipTapImage.configure({
    HTMLAttributes: {
      loading: "lazy",
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",
      sizes: "(max-width: 500px) 320px, (max-width: 1320px) 640px, 1280px",
      class: `h-auto w-full`,
    },
  }),
  Underline,
  Video,
  Youtube.configure({
    HTMLAttributes: {
      class: "youtube",
      loading: "lazy",
      height: "320",
      width: "640",
    },
  }),
];
```

And this is useEditor code.

```js
const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: editorExtensions,
    content: data?.content || "",
    editorProps: {
      attributes: {
        class:
          "prose w-full focus:outline-none prose-primary-600 min-h-[320px] max-w-none",
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some useEffect is not coding well, so i check every single useEffect and fix that.